# interval in nodejs app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nonblocking, data-synchronization

I'm newbie, and i try to create nodejs app (with mongo database). I have a problem with interval function. example:

In severside: 
I have peace of code:

```
var test = setInterval(function(){
               getData()
           },1000);
var getData = function(){
   // get data from database then return to client
}
```

Problem is how I control when getData is finish then excute next interval. As i know javascript is non blocking so interval and getData function is in different thread, right?

Anyone have solution for this?

Comment: Why do you need `setInterval` ? I assume there is only one thread..

Comment: because I try to make it realtime, so i need interval.

Comment: Real-time is a very vast term. What exactly you want do ? `setInterval` seems invalid solution in most of the cases. There are less expensive solutions than this...Your code will always execute in intervals even if there are no changes in the DB..

Comment: my app open socketio, and in server i create a interval to make real-time. You have better solutions for this?

Comment: have a look at this [semaphore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/semaphore) npm package

Comment: Push/Emit content over `socket` after Mongo events.. Read this: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html

Comment: you need to learn more about `socket.io` :-  http://socket.io/

Comment: @RayonDabre exactly i push/emit content after mongo events, the point is   previous getData function not finish yet, interval function run next getData function, so it make bad performance

Comment: Using `setInterval` will hamper performance..

Answer (score 1):

You can use setTimeout instead of setInterval:

```
function getData(){
   // get data from database then return to client
   setTimeout(getData, 1000);
}

getData();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am doing something similar to this in a node.js app:

```
let _ = require('lodash');

function getData() {

    let previousResponse;

    let run = function() {

        let currentResponse = someMethodToGetDataFromDb();

        //Only send data to client if something has actually changed
        if(!_.isEqual(previousResponse, currentResponse)) {
            previousResponse = currentResponse;
            sendDataToClient(currentResponse);

            //This calls itself but ensures there is only ever one call to
            //the db at one time.
            setTimeout(run, 3000); 
        }

    };

    run();
}
```